# Prove that angles in the given projective geometry setting are equal

Tags: projective-geometry, cross-ratio

We are given triangle $DIV$. On the side $IV$ a point $U$ is chosen, such that $UDI$ is the right angle. Point $P$ on $IV$ is such that $(I,U;P,V)=-1$ (harmonic conjugates that is). Prove that angles $UDP$ an $UDV$ are equal.

No ideas how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the harmonic conjugate? What does it mean if $(I,U;P,V)=-1$?

Comment: @FareedAF $(A,B;C,D)$ is cross-ratio of points $A,B,C,D$. See wikipedia for what cross-ratio is. If cross-ratio equals $-1$, then $D$ is said to be the harmonic conjugate of $A,B,C$.